# Installing new hard drive on dual boot system: is boot loader only on hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, bootloader

Sorry for such a basic question but I have to be sure.
I will replace my hard drive with new hard drive. Currently I have dual boot (Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu), which boots with GRUB2. 
Is boot loader only on hard drive? Considering this article it is: http://www.howtogeek.com/187789/dual-booting-explained-how-you-can-have-multiple-operating-systems-on-your-computer/

*"Your computer’s operating system is generally installed on its internal hard drive. When you boot your computer, the BIOS loads the **boot loader from the hard drive** and the boot loader boots the installed operating system."*

When hard drive is replaced, new OS can be normally installed? Or do I have to configure some additional stuff before replacing the hard drive?

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: Yes, if you put a _new_ hard drive in your system, you can directly install a new OS onto that hard drive, which will install the needed bootloader. No, you should not need to configure anything before doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the computer boots, special code in the read-only memory (BIOS or EFI) reads a boot loader from one of several possible locations (hard disk, USB flash drive, optical drive, network) and gives it control.

- If you *replace* the hard disk with a new one, the new disk won't have any boot loader on it; you will need to install an operating system, or else restore a full-system backup. You can use for example [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make a full backup of the old hard disk.
- If you *add* a hard disk, the old disk still has the boot loader.

P.S. Please read the comment of user waltinator and follow the suggested instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `/etc/fstab` mounts partitions by UUID, e.g.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=83a64b80-5a37-4659-b797-221b88ef41f8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=12817b99-9d2b-4357-a4ca-c11eab672a20 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=339b7a56-3b67-47e8-87e1-f483296a39bd none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

You will have to replace the UUIDs of your old disk with the UUIDs of your new disk.

I did this recently, but had to restore the MBR from a different backup. This step is necessary, but not complete.

Run `blkid` and fix your on-disk `fstab` while you're booted from the CD/USB key.